# Combining 2 Bytes (HighByte/LowByte) to a signed Int in C#

Tags: c#, byte

I have been struggling with this for the past 3 hours and I'm not coming right.
I have the highByte/lowByte values which i need to combine into a signed int called temp(I think). I know the input and the desired output, but at this point I'm thinking this might be completely offtrack.

```
int temp = ((highByte) & 0xFF) << 8 | (lowByte) & 0xFF;
```

I'm using this function, but it is not returning the desired output.

There must be something wrong with this conversion, or my logic i have applied to this problem. The Desired outcome is:

> If both highByte/lowByte bytes have the value 255, the output should
>   be -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int`  is 4-byte integer value (its system name Int32). if you want the upper byte of highByte to be treated as sign, cast right part of expression as `short` (Int16)

```
int temp = (short)(((highByte) & 0xFF) << 8 | (lowByte) & 0xFF);
```